# remove elements from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

this the forth project from the odin project, all tests passed but the fifth one which required removing all elements failed and when i run the code it returns an array with half elements in original array before mutating.

I don't know why IT DOESN'T RETURN AN EMPTY ARRAY.in the fifth test.

```
const removeFromArray = function (array, ...deleteElement) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array.includes(deleteElement[i])) {
            array.splice(array.indexOf(deleteElement[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
};

const randomArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(removeFromArray(randomArray, 1, 2, 3, 4));
```

and this the test

```
const removeFromArray = require('./removeFromArray')

describe('removeFromArray', () => {
  test('removes a single value', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)).toEqual([1, 2, 4]);
  });
  test('removes multiple values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)).toEqual([1, 4]);
  });
  test('ignores non present values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 7, "tacos")).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
  test('ignores non present values, but still works', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 7, 2)).toEqual([1, 3, 4]);
  });
  test.skip('can remove all values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 2, 3, 4)).toEqual([]);
  });
  test.skip('works with strings', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray(["hey", 2, 3, "ho"], "hey", 3)).toEqual([2, "ho"]);
  });
  test.skip('only removes same type', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3], "1", 3)).toEqual([1, 2]);
  });
});
```

Comment: About your previous question which has been deleted now, I just wanted to say that, there are always concepts in programming that when you first learn them, it doesn't make any sense to you and seems unclear, but when you go ahead, learn more and most importantly do a few projects, in some moments, bang! You're gonna realize what this is for, what is our intention to use the constructor for example, etc, So what's important here is to do your search but if you've noticed the general idea, it's okay for now, Stop overthinking about it, Keep going! You will realize, It just takes some time :)

Comment: @ArianHosseini . I searched a lot before actually asking here. The problem was that I was very distracted at that time. Many questions came to my mind about whether the content or sources of the course were out of date. So I asked just to see if what I was thinking was wrong or not. All in all, I now think that this article was not appropriate for a person at the beginning of his journey with the OOP. Thank you for your reply, it means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` you are looping trough the wrong element. It should be `deleteElement.length`, not `array.length`

```js
const removeFromArray = function(array, ...deleteElement) {
  for (let i = 0; i < deleteElement.length; i++) {
    if (array.includes(deleteElement[i])) {
      array.splice(array.indexOf(deleteElement[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  return array;
};

const randomArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(removeFromArray(randomArray, 1, 2, 3, 4));
```

EDIT:
although this will not work correctly when there are 2 same element to delete in the array. Here is another implementation which is deleting all matched indexes and not only the first one.

```js
const removeFromArray = function(array, ...deleteElement) {
  for (let i = 0; i < deleteElement.length; i++) {
    let foundIndex = array.indexOf(deleteElement[i]);
    while (foundIndex !== -1) {
      array.splice(foundIndex, 1);
      foundIndex = array.indexOf(deleteElement[i]);
    }
  }
  return array;
};

const randomArray = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4];
console.log(removeFromArray(randomArray, 1));
```

Comment: It works, thanks!. but I don't understand why looping throw deleteElement while I use looping through array itself to search for if deleteElement is in this array or not ?

Comment: first you need to loop trough `deleteElements`, because these are the items we need to search for.
Looping trough the `array` and searching if array contains an item to delete is done "behind the scenes"  in the `includes` function

Comment: also added an second implementation which will work with duplicates in array, so 
`removeFromArray([1,2,3,1,4], 1)` will return `2,3,4`

Comment: Why do you use a classic for loop rather than a `for..of` loop?

Comment: @Dawid.T thanks alot I'm honestly so grateful.

Comment: @Dr-Vortex I'm not used to for of loop, I use for loop to iterate most of the time

Comment: `for..of` loops are really useful and you should [check them out](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

Your function iterates over the wrong variable (`array.length`)

```js
const removeFromArray = function (array, ...deleteElement) {
    for (let element of deleteElement) {
        if (array.includes(element)) {
            array.splice(array.indexOf(element), 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it passed too, but I don't understand why looping through deleteElement not the array Itself ?

Comment: Because you want to remove all of the elements in deleteElement. If you loop through the array, it won't iterate properly. For example, `removeFromArray([1, 4], 2, 3, 4)` would not have removed the 4.

Comment: thank you very much honestly this information helped me alot, I try the code and it didn't remove the "4" already, now I'm clearly understand thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the for loop is using the `array.length` property dynamically, which means it is going to be evaluated every time you pass the loop, so since you are removing the elements from the original array, this value is not constant and at some point the array length value and the `i` counter will get out of sync.

You just need to **save the array length value in a variable** so it stays the same after you remove the objects from the array.

```js
var arrLen = array.length;
for (let i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    ...
}
```

**Update:**

Pasting the full code here plus a live sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/bcngr/sbk1yhmn/

```js
const removeFromArray = function (array, ...deleteElement) {
    var arrLen = array.length; // Save the length value before any modification to the array
    for (let i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) { // use the variable instead of array.length
        if (array.includes(deleteElement[i])) {
            array.splice(array.indexOf(deleteElement[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
};

const randomArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(removeFromArray(randomArray, 1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but I tried this solution it return the same output not an empty array

Comment: This makes no sense... The length of the array would not affect anything, and it still does not get outputs properly.

Comment: See the working live sample above.

Comment: Yes it is actually returning an empty array, thank you and I'm sorry it was my mistake. but I don't understand what's the difference between adding arrLen and array.length while both are the same value ?